# Can I get the updated value of a variable in a closure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Note: React App.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have a function that sets up an object with keys that hold a set of numbers and returns an updater function.

I have 3 components that call this on click on a number matrix, and if I log the result of the return of that function call then and there, I get the updated object of set values back.

```js
function App() {

  const fn = (keys) => {
    const obj = {};
    // loop through keys to create -> obj = { [key]: new Set() };

    const updater = (num, key) => {
        obj[key].has(num) ? obj[key].delete(num) : obj[key].add(num);
        return obj;
    }

    return updater;
  }

  // initialize
  const updateFn = fn(['key1', 'key2', 'key3']);

  // correctly update the sets values and return ALL updates on change
  const updateAndLog = (num, key) => console.log(updateFn(num, key)) 

  // But when I try to call it from elsewhere in a callback to send to an api such as:
  const handleSend = () => {
    console.log(updateFn(0, 'key1')) // { key1: {0}, key2: {}, key3: {} };
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Component index={1} handleUpdate={updateAndLog} .. />
      <Component index={2} handleUpdate={updateAndLog} .. />
      <Component index={3} handleUpdate={updateAndLog} .. />
      <button onClick={handleSend}>Send Data</button>
    </>
  )

}
```

It returns empty, and with a new object with just that 0 stored in the first key. Now, I know I could store these in state as I go, but I'm trying to avoid that in this scenario.

If you have any recommendations on how this might be achieved would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Where you declare your `updateFn` ?

Comment: @Carr All of the code is within the component body, though I have tried moving both the functions outside the scope, as well as storing the variable (obj) outside both the inner function scope to the main function, as a ref, and outside the entire function scope also

Comment: your `updateAndLog` would take two args, what's the usage of `handleUpdate` in the `Componet`

Comment: @Carr this is just an extra step to log the result here. Usually the component receives the updateFn directly, and it passes the num and index in from it's callback inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateFn` gets recreated every time the component renders.

So you could do this to prevent it from being recreated.

```
const updateFnRef = useRef(fn(['key1', 'key2', 'key3']))
const updateFn = updateFnRef.current;
```